# How can I incorporate cluster-robust standard errors into a randomization test using the 'ritest' function?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, permutation, simulation, inference

I'm currently attempting to perform a randomization test following several regressions. However, I'm encountering difficulties in incorporating cluster-robust standard errors into my randomization test. Please find my code below. I have attempted various approaches, but none have been successful so far.

Can you provide guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue?

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
library(fixest)

reg32 <- feols(op_dummy ~ bartik | ibge_cod + year, panel.id=~ibge_cod + year, 
               vcov=~ibge_cod, data=df_clean)

summary(reg32)
#        Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# bartik  10.7117    8.74312  1.22516   0.22057 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# RMSE: 0.129153     Adj. R2: 0.231909                                     
#                  Within R2: 3.642e-5  


library(ritest)

est_ri <- ritest(reg32, resampvar="bartik", reps=1000, seed=4321, verbose=TRUE,
                 stack=FALSE, cluster="ibge_cod")
```

Error I get:

```
Running 1000 parallel RI simulations in a PSOCK cluster across 4 CPU cores. Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val):
4 nodes produced errors; first error: in fixest::demean(Xtreat_samp, fmat, nthre...:
Argument 'X' must be either: i) a numeric matrix (or vector), ii) a
list, iii) a formula, or iv) an object of class 'fixest'. Problem: it is
a matrix but it is not numeric (instead it is of type 'character').
```

Things I have tried:

- Attempted to remove all the missing values (NAs).
- Ran the code setting `stack = TRUE`.
- Used `cluster = ~ibge_cod` instead of `cluster = "ibge_cod"`.
- Transformed the `ibge_cod` variable into a character type.

I am determined to solve the problem at hand and gain a deeper understanding of it.

Things I have tried:

- Attempted to remove all the missing values (NAs).
- Ran the code without setting `stack = TRUE`.
- Used `cluster = ~ibge_cod` instead of `cluster = "ibge_cod"`.
- Transformed the `ibge_cod` variable into a character type.

I am determined to solve the problem at hand and gain a deeper understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is obviously that your `op_dummy` isn't numeric. It can be reproduced using sample data.

```
library(fixest)

co_est <- feols(dummy ~ b_treat + b_dayscorab | b_pair + miss_b_dayscorab + round2 + round3, 
                vcov=~b_block, data=colombia)
# Error in feols(dummy ~ b_treat + b_dayscorab | b_pair + miss_b_dayscorab +  : 
#   The left hand side must be a numeric matrix (or vector) with 1 column.
# Problem: it is not numeric (instead it is of type 'character').
```

You can code it as integer.

```
colombia$dummy |> head()
# [1] "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" NA 

colombia$dummy <- as.integer(as.factor(colombia$dummy)) - 1
colombia$dummy |> head()
# [1]  1  0  0  0  1 NA

co_est <- feols(dummy ~ b_treat + b_dayscorab | b_pair + miss_b_dayscorab + round2 + round3, 
                vcov=~b_block, data=colombia)
# NOTE: 1,020 observations removed because of NA values (LHS: 1,020).

summary(co_est)
# OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: dummy
# Observations: 2,346 
# Fixed-effects: b_pair: 31,  miss_b_dayscorab: 2,  round2: 2,  round3: 2
# Standard-errors: Clustered (b_block) 
#              Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# b_treat     -0.020560   0.018658 -1.10194   0.27475    
# b_dayscorab  0.114396   0.006622 17.27395 < 2.2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# RMSE: 0.433418     Adj. R2: 0.237184
#                  Within R2: 0.199278

ritest(co_est, 'b_treat', strata='b_pair', cluster='b_block', reps=1e3, seed=1234)
#           Call: feols(fml = dummy ~ b_treat + b_dayscorab | b_pair + miss_b_dayscorab + round2 + round3, data = colombia, vcov = ~b_block)
#    Res. var(s): b_treat
#             H0: b_treat=0
#  Strata var(s): b_pair
#         Strata: 31
# Cluster var(s): b_block
#       Clusters: 63
#      Num. reps: 1000
# ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
#   T(obs)         c         n     p=c/n     SE(p)   CI 2.5%  CI 97.5%  
# -0.02056       430      1000      0.43   0.02576    0.3876    0.4724  
# ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
# Note: Confidence interval is with respect to p=c/n. 
# Note: c = #{|T| >= |T(obs)|}
```

---

*Data:*

```
data("colombia", package='ritest')
colombia <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(colombia))
colombia$dummy <- as.character(+(colombia$dayscorab > 4))
```